# Javascript Regex match missing odd index

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor client code which uses regex to match words in a sentence, it matches fine but only on index 0 and even number index. why is it not matching on every index number? Thanks

```js
  let matches = '2006 BLUE TOYOTA COROLLA 120 SER SEDAN'.match(/[A-Z0-9]*/gi)
  console.log('yr: ', matches[0])       //2006
  console.log('color: ', matches[1])    // blank, why?
  console.log('color?: ', matches[2])   //BLUE
  console.log('make?: ', matches[3])    // blank, why?
  console.log('make: ', matches[4])     //TOYOTA
  console.log('modle: ', matches[6])    //COROLLA
})
```

Comment: use `+` instead of `*`. `[A-Z0-9]*` matches the zero-length string between each word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it happens because you use * operator instead of +
difference between them is:

*  - 0 or more of the preceding expression

+  - 1 or more of the preceding expression

so in your case * operator takes this empty space as "0 or more" and thinks, that it is a separate element,
expression, that you probably want is:

```
let matches = '2006 BLUE TOYOTA COROLLA 120 SER SEDAN'.match(/[A-Z0-9]+/gi)
```